# Exporting QGIS project to Mapnik XML?

Tags: qgis, export, mapnik

Is it possible to export a QGIS project to Mapnik xml?

I'm using QGIS 2.4 and Quantumnik does not seem to work with that version.

Comment: Have you been able to find solution?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know it is not possible because the Quantumnik plugin is supported until version 1.8. In that case I have seen that the export function works but you must paying attention to use the "old symbology" option for the layers styles.