# Is export of QGIS layer styles to mapnik possible?

Tags: qgis, mapnik

Is it possible to export layer styles to mapnik xml from QGIS?

As I understand it, it used to be possible once by means of quantumnik plug-in, which is discontinued now.

I see this issue [has already been discussed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111950/is-it-possible-to-export-a-qgis-project-to-mapnik-xml) two years ago but to no avail.

Is that it? No other ways to do it? I refuse to believe it is not possible.

It's rather frustrating to have a map ready in QGIS and to be unable to export the styles to mapnik sitting on the same data!

You may call it a "duplicate question", but 4 years have passed since it was asked last time, so maybe something has changed?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  There are a number of options for reviving old questions provided at https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/options-when-question-is-duplicate-of-one-with-no-inadequate-old-answers  In this instance I'll place a bounty on the earlier question to see whether we can get an answer contemporary with QGIS 3 added.

Comment: You are correct that the question was asked years ago and may be out of date, but PolyGeo has started a bounty on it to attract more attention, which is a better method of doing so rather than opening multiple questions.

Comment: All right! Let's hope a champion will come around and save us all! There must be a way! I bet someone is sitting on a custom script exactly for this. And - thanks, PolyGeo!